# How to create a new camera that matches the active 3d-view, can it be done?

Tags: 3d-view, blender-internal-render-engine, camera

Can one add a new camera in the 3d-view that matches the current view in that viewport? Is there a quick-key shortcut?

If, for instance, you have a 3d-view port set to orthographic, the added camera would also have to be orthographic and the orthographic scaling would have to be some certain setting etc, for the camera to match whats seen in the viewport.

Can this be done when creating a new camera?

[image]

Comment: I don't know of a single hotkey to do this, but you could add a new camera and snap it to the view with [Shift]+[A] > [R], [Ctrl]+[Numpad 0], [Ctrl]+[Alt]+[Numpad 0].

Comment: @Knuckles209cp I don't think so, that question is asking about aiming a current camera at an object, this person is asking for a way to add a camera and set it to the view.

Comment: "The absolute quickest way to do this is to find a good position in the 3d viewport by navigating as normal with the mouse. Next, select the camera and use Ctrl + Alt + Numpad0 or from the 3d view header, View > Align View > Align Active Camera to View to position/point the camera in the direction you are facing in the viewport.
"

Comment: @PGmath Just [Shift]+[A] > [R], [Ctrl]+[Alt]+[Numpad 0] without the [Ctrl]+[Numpad 0] :)

Comment: Close enough for my purposes, but it would be cool if one could add a camera and not have to reposition, align and set parameters manually. Thanx for answers!